# why exceptions are not catched in the errorChannel of spring integration when the messages are sent using the control bus

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring integration message stored in database. this message was stored after an exception occurred and  catched by the errorChannel.

now when i try to replay this message using the control bus, if an exception occurred, i see an error in my logs but no exception was catched by the errorChannel.

here is the code i used:

```
    @Qualifier("control-bus.replay.channel")
    MessageChannel controlBus;

    public void redo(Message<?> msg){
      controlBus.send(
      MessageBuilder.withPayload(
      "@mybean.transform(headers['myMessage'])") 
      .setHeader("myMessage", msg).build());
   }
```

i tried to add the errorChannel in the header of the message but did not work.

so i'm wondering if this is the default behavior of the control bus and how can i override it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with the Control Bus per se. It is a behavior dictated by the `MessageChannel` type you use to send that message.

By default a `DirectChannel` is used to wire endpoints. When you send a message directly into that channel (as you do in your code snippet), the exception is thrown directly to this caller ignoring all the possible error handling configuration. Imagining you do a regular Java call stack without any thread shifting. So, exception is just thrown to you.
That works well, of course, if your entire flow on that channel is direct: no any queue or an executor channels configuration in between.

From here it would be great to see your `control-bus.replay.channel` and Control Bus configuration.